# CQWP XSLT ddwrt:Today() return PST time zone instead of Local time zone

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt, content-query-web-part, date-time, ddwrt

I am working on CQWP webpart in **Office 365(SharePoint Online)**. I have to get today's date for date comparison. I have use `xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"` for getting current date.

But it returns USA(**PST**) date regardless of local time zone. Now i need to get date for **GMT+5:30**.

I have checked region setting for my Office 365. Those are set to local time zone.

I have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:Today()),1033,2)" />
```

And

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:TodayIso()),1033,2)" />
```

How can i get data of local time zone in CQWP. Is there any other way to achive the same?